# Can I customise Getter & Setter name (not body) in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example,

For private variable

```
private int _sampleField;
```

Eclipse generates

```
public int get_sampleField() {
    return _sampleField;
}

public void set_sampleField(int _sampleField) {
    this._sampleField = _sampleField;
}
```

Whereas I want

```
public int sampleField() {
    return _sampleField;
}

public void setSampleField(int _sampleField) {
    this._sampleField = _sampleField;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get Eclipse to ignore the '_' in your field names when creating the getter and setter (and in other places):

Open 'Preferences > Java > Code Style'

Select the 'Fields' entry in the 'conventions for variable names' table and click 'Edit...'

Set the 'Prefix list' to '_'

Eclipse now knows that you are using the '_' prefix and will ignore it when creating the getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

In the source code window of the desired class, right-click to bring up the context-menu. From there. select `Source` and then select `Generate Getters and Setters`. A wizard will then popup where you will be able to continue.

Or could you click anywhere in the code in Eclipse, and do `Sources > Generate Getters and Setters`

Comment: First, thanks for the hashCode example, but how to build a template to suit my case is still not obvious to me. That ${field}, which field it is referring to? The selected/highlighted field?

Comment: Second, if I have to achieve this through Content Assist, I assume the way to use it would be different. I wouldn't able to select all fields that I want to generate getter/setter do it at one go but instead I have to do it one by one for each field?

Comment: You want to modify `Getters and Setters`... and that is where `Getters and Setters` is at...

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding here.. I don't see Eclipse offer a way to modify the naming pattern of those auto-generated Getter/Setters. Wait, I'm using Kepler, maybe a newer version has this feather??

Comment: I am using Eclipse LUNA. Most likely yes. Sorry, I should have stated that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can have whatever name for the getter and setter methods you want. In fact they don't have to even seem related to your variable. I would not suggest that because that is not a good programing practice. Try it and you will see.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson This question is not about naming convention. I saw in other posts that you have strong personal opinions about naming convention but please don't contaminate this post.